# What is the more accurate way of stating the correctness of a PK encryption scheme?

Tags: encryption, public-key, terminology

Is it more accurate to state that a public key encryption scheme is correct if for all $m \in M$ and $(pk, sk) \in \operatorname{Gen}(1^k)$

***a***. $\operatorname{Dec}_{sk}(\operatorname{Enc}_{pk}(m))=m\;$ or,

***b***. $\Pr[\operatorname{Dec}_{sk}(\operatorname{Enc}_{pk}(m))=m] = 1 - \operatorname{negl}(k)\;$ or,

***c***. does it depend on the scheme or some other factor?

Comment: I'd say that (1) shows correctness. But that's more about programmatic correctness than anything else. It doesn't show necessarily that the scheme is secure - particularly it doesn't show that you cannot decrypt in any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deciding among ***a*** or ***b*** is a matter of choice of definition of public-key encryption. Clearly ***a*** is desirable, and ***b*** is a fallback in order to allow some interesting cryptosystems. The definition is chosen according to the cryptosystem studied, as in ***c***.

As pointed by poncho in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/191357), in ***b*** as it stands, the meaning is that for all keys and messages, there's negligible probability that decryption does not yield the original message. The encryption algorithm is re-expressed as a deterministic algorithm with an extra input $r$ for the random allowing to achieve CPA security, and it's really meant that
$$\Pr[\operatorname{Dec}_{sk}(\operatorname{Enc}_{pk}(m, r))=m]\quad=\quad1 - \operatorname{negl}(k)$$
where the probability is computed over all inputs $r$ randomizing the encryption. Such tolerance for rare failures is necessary for some cryptosystems, e.g. those based on [Hidden Field Equations](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/072).

There is at least one other popular alternative to ***b***: we can require that all except vanishingly few keys allow certain encryption and decryption of all messages $m\in M$. We thus compute the probability that there exists a message $m$ and random input $r$ making encryption/decryption fail over the set of keys produced by $\operatorname{Gen}(1^k)$ (or even more precisely, over the set of random inputs to that algorithm re-expressed as a deterministic one with random input $r$). That's the definition of public-key encryption given by Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell's [*Introduction to Modern Cryptography*](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/imc.html) 2<sup>nd</sup> edition. Their rationale is allowing RSA with a probabilistic prime test. They explicitly choose to ignore the exceptions.

Update: in IMC 3<sup>rd</sup> edition, that changed slightly. The probability is computed over the randomness of $\operatorname{Gen}$ and $\operatorname{Enc}$. I think it will stick as the standard definition of public-key encryption.

Yet other cryptosystems are correct with ***a*** only, e.g. RSA with proven primes, or ECIES when working with families of curves and generators of proven order.

Comment: Actually, for $b$, what is generally meant is that the encryption is randomized; hence, it really is $\Pr[\operatorname{Dec}_{sk}(\operatorname{Enc}_{pk}(m, r))=m] = 1 - \operatorname{negl}(k)\;$ which we insist holds for any valid $sk, pk$ pair, and any message $m$ (and which $r$ is the only random variable)

Comment: @poncho: thanks for showing me the light!